# SyntaxError in Python

Tags: python-3.x

I got a quick question about my program. I want to assign 0 to all the variables named `rdf12(i)`, like `rdf12(1) = 0 rdf12(2) = 0`. Here is my code:

```
for i in range(200):
    rdf12(i) = 0
```

But it turned out not that easy and I had an error said:

```
SyntaxError: can't assign to function call
```

So how can I edit my code to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

The item access operator in Python is `[]`, not `()`.

So you probably want `rdf12[i] = 0` instead. However, this only works if you have a list named `rdf12` that already contains 200+ elements. Not if you have/want actual variables named `rdf120`, `rdf121`, ... - if that't the case you need to refactor your code (while it would still be possible, I'm not going to post [that solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18862378/298479) here since it would be incredibly ugly). Anyway, this is what you should use:

```
rdf12 = [0 for i in range(200)]
```

That gives you a list containing 200 zeroes. You can then access the elements using `rdf12[0]`, `rdf12[1]`, ..., `rdf12[199]` and assign other values to them etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have brackets `(` and `)` as part of the variable name as this syntax is used to call a function. You are effectively trying to call a function `rdf12` with the values of `i`.

If you name your variables `rdf12_0`, `rdf12_1`, etc you may be able to access them through the `locals()` function which returns a dict of local variable declarations, however I believe making modifications to this dict is **not guaranteed to work** and as such is a really bad idea.

```
>>> rdf12_0 = 0
>>> lcls = locals()
>>> print(lcls['rdf12_0'])
0
>>> name = 'rdf12_' + str(0)
>>> lcls[name] = 34
>>> rdf12_0
34
```

I would suggest instead, storing your values in a `list`:

```
>>> rdf12 = [34, 12, 9, 97]
>>> rdf12[0]
34
>>> rdf12[1]
12
>>> for i in rdf12:
...     print(i)
... 
34
12
9
97
```